# SQL SELECT DISTINCT confusion

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know I can select distinct like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, title, photo FROM myTable;
```

But when I want to `SELECT id, title` but with distinct `title`, what should I do?

I mean I want to select rows and avoid duplicate titles. Because maybe there be duplicate photos, but it's not important, I need only distinct `titles`. How then should I select `photo` and `title` fields and at the same time set `title` to be unique and distinct?

Comment: Try adding `group by id, photo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  id, title, photo FROM myTable GROUP BY title;
```

simple select query with group by will work here.

Comment: I don't know what the application of this query is but, you will only get one of the photos with this query. A group concatenate function will need to be applied to the photo column of you want to recover all photos from that title.

Comment: @user3853834 no problem, please mark an answer if it help you, and an upvote will be a plus . :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your data, but basically you are looking to force photo to return a single value, along with your distinct title.  Something like this:

```
SELECT title, MAX(photo)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY title
```

would do that, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct Photo Menas all photo without no repetition
SELECT  id, photo FROM myTable GROUP BY title;